# Horizontal full width scroll in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Flutter Listview component uses scrollDirection to do horizontal scrolling.
How do i set the width of the individual items to window width and scroll one page at a time?

Comment: Not clear. Can you edit your question ? Possibly with a gif explaining what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a [**PageView**](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) instead of a *ListView* as it works just like you described. It fits better your purpose because you don't have to write all the logic to manage the threshold of the pages and it automatically allocates the entire screen width for each element.